# How to share EmbeddedGraphDatabase instance across multiple JSP pages?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, neo4j, embedded-database

Is there any way that I can share EmbeddedGraphDatabase instance across multiple JSP pages ?
The problem is that once you start tomcat server and instantiate EmbeddedGraphDatabase for a particular Neo4j DB , The database will remain locked , if you try to instantiate another graphDB for the same .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` is your object and you want it's instance to be shared in multiple JSP pages of your application.

You need to put it's instance to the application scope and it will be visible to all your application's classes and JSP pages.

To do that you need to implement `ServletContextListener` interface:

```
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
       EmbeddedGraphDatabase db = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase();
       event.getServletContext().setAttribute("yourAttrName", db);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
       event.getServletContext().removeAttribute("yourAttrName");
    }
}
```

Define it in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.YourContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And to get it use:

```
EmbeddedGraphDatabase db = getServletContext().getAttribute("yourAttrName");
```

Hope this helps.